# Why does `<C-k> {char1} {char2}` work for digraphs but `{char1} <BS> {char2}?

Tags: key-bindings, digraphs

Based on the documentation of `digraphs-use` (`:help digraphs-use`) it should be possible to do both `<C-k> {char1} {char2}` and `{char1} <BS> {char2}`, but the second one does nothing and `<BS>` simply deletes the first character.

I've tried `<C-v>` and pressing the backspace key and it does put in `<BS>`, which makes me think I am indeed pressing the right key.

Comment: From `:help digraphs-use`, first paragraph: "The first is always available; the second only when the `'digraph'` option is set".

Comment: @lcd047 add this as an answer?